# 4 digit, 12 pin display connected to arduino

Tags: arrays, methods, arduino, display, arduino-c++

I'm trying to make a 4 digit, 12 pin display stopwatch.
The display is with 7 digit line pins (A, B, C, D, E, F, G) and 4 digit pins (D1, D2, D3, D4). I don't need the twelfth pin.
Line pins are for activating single lines of a digit and digit pins for activating the digit.
The lines light up in all the numbers which are activated. Then I made the methods for each number
and digit.
4 methods for activating digits and 10 methods for activating single numbers (from 0 to 9)

[image]

So  if I want to display a zero I have this method:

```
void NumberZero(){
digitalWrite(pinA, HIGH);
digitalWrite(pinB, HIGH);
digitalWrite(pinC, HIGH);
digitalWrite(pinD, HIGH);
digitalWrite(pinE, HIGH);
digitalWrite(pinF, HIGH);
digitalWrite(pinG, LOW);
}
```

And if I want to activate the first slot/digit I need this method:

```
void FirstSlot(){
digitalWrite(D1, LOW);
digitalWrite(D2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(D3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(D4, HIGH);
}
```

So at the start, the first 9 seconds are pretty easy, I just have to activate the fourth slot and then all the following numbers:

```
FourthSlot();
NumberOne();
delay(1000);
NumberTwo();
delay(1000);
NumberThree();
delay(1000);
NumberFour();
delay(1000);
NumberFive();
delay(1000);
NumberSix();
delay(1000);
NumberSeven();
delay(1000);
NumberEight();
delay(1000);
NumberNine();
delay(1000);
```

Then to avoid blurry numbers when I start to add more digits in to the mix I made a cleaning method:

```
void Clean(){
digitalWrite(pinA, LOW);
digitalWrite(pinB, LOW);
digitalWrite(pinC, LOW);
digitalWrite(pinD, LOW);
digitalWrite(pinE, LOW);
digitalWrite(pinF, LOW);
digitalWrite(pinG, LOW);
}
```

So now after those 9 seconds I have the tenth second which looks like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 500; x++) {
  Clean();
  ThirdSlot();
  NumberOne();
  delay(1);
  Clean();
  FourthSlot();
  NumberZero();
  delay(1);
}
```

So as you can see we need to rapidly switch between two digits in a matter of 1 millisecond to display them separately at the same time. This is to demonstrate how numbers are displayed on this 12 pin, 4 digit display. But what I need, is to display 60 different numbers in a minute. So the best solution would be to put all these 10 number methods in an array.

My question is - How can I put all my Number methods in an array? Is it even possible to store methods in an array?
So instead of this:

```
NumberZero();
NumberOne();
NumberTwo();
NumberThree();
```

I could do something like this:

```
Number[0];
Number[1];
Number[2];
Number[3];
```

Comment: What is your question? What specific problem are you facing? Can you [edit] the question, to clarify?

Comment: You'd be better off not having functions like 'NumberThree' and implementing a single 'Number(int[] digiitPins)'.   Then you have something like an array that maps from the number to display to the set of digit pins.  That is, don't inject parameters into methods by cut'n'pasting near-identical methods, inject parameters as arguments to the method.

Comment: use a library. why reinvent the wheel? there is more then one in Library Manager: DeanIsMe/SevSeg, sigvaldm/SevenSeg

Comment: Yes. It can be simplified. Create an 8x10 array with 10 rows and 8 columns. The columns are the pins A...G+DP and the rows are the number index. Then call a general function with a pointer to the row. Before calling it, set the correct _slot/digit_. This is just a different way of expressing the idea @aguest wrote.

Comment: Something I learned in my first few months as a professional programmer: don't write code if you can write data.